# Aggregation query using Sequelize and SQLITE

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize and SQLite, and having a table like:

```
A | B
a | 1
b | 2
c | 3
```

I would like to create a map using a query via Sequelize, giving the following result:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

How can I do that? I can do a `findAll` and then a `docs.reduce(...)`, but I would like to extract that directly from SQLite if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of sqlite supports the [JSON1](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) extension, you can use something like

```
SELECT json_group_object(A, B) FROM yourtable;
```

to get a single row holding a single column that's a string holding a JSON object. That should be trivial to convert to a javascript map.

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ded0ed205ca48b7a1b74ad1fe726362f)

Comment: How do you do that using `sequelize`?

Comment: @IonicăBizău That's an ORM, right? They usually have some way to execute normal SQL statements.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is a Sequelize-way to do that, but running a custom query will work too. Thanks!